# Using "worse" after the verb "grow"

Tags: phrase-usage

> **As the problems of poverty grow worse**, a class of rabble (Pobel) is thus created. 
>   —Terry Pinkard

I was stumbled across the above piece and when I read the Terry Pinkard's bolded sentence,
I wondered if it were common in English language. So I searched on The New York Times to verify if there were other examples of the phrase "poverty grow worse". Before searching there, I expected to find a remarkable number of examples, but I found nothing. Thus I searched on the most important British newspapers, but, again, I found nothing.

This circumstace seems strange to me because the fact that poverty is growing is rather common nowadays.

However, apart further considerations, this question arise from the fact that the words "grow" and "worse", used togheter as above, sound strange and almost contradictory.

Can anybody explain and clarify if I'm imagining things or if I have observed an unusual way to write?

Comment: I'd say [_worsen_](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/worsen), but that's probably as archaic as I am. :-)

Comment: *Growing worse* is common.  The former word describes the rate of change: the *badness* is *growing*.  A positive rate-of-change modifier can modify a negative word, so some people say things like *increasingly smaller*.  At first glance, this appears to be an oxymoron, but it's not: *increasingly* describes the rate of change in *smallness*.

Comment: Another manner of expressing this is "get worse".  (US, northeast)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, the word *grow* is used to mean *become*.  Consider the sentence rewritten:

> As the problems of poverty **become** worse, a class of rabble (Pobel) is thus created.

This is [definition #7](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/grow) of grow here:

> To come to be by a gradual process or by degrees; become: grow angry; grow closer.

The reason you didn't find anything when you searched for "poverty grow worse" is that poverty isn't what's growing--the problems are.  If you search the NYT website for ["problems grow worse"](http://query.nytimes.com/search/sitesearch/#/problems+grow+worse) you get quite a few hits, and you have to realize that's not even counting sentences like the one you posted, where *problems* is separated from *grow worse* by other descriptors.

Comment: I like this answer best because you've not only dealt with the grammar/semantics, but you've also explained *why* OP might have been misled by his own research. Of course, we native speakers usually have the benefit of knowing what answer we *expect* to find, so we're more likely to question our methods if we don't get the "right" answer straight away.

Answer (score 2):

It's not particularly common, but it is entirely valid. In this case, the sentence is constructed thusly:

> The problems

This is the noun and the core of the sentence.

> The problems grow

The (number of) problems is increasing

> The problems grow worse

The number of problems is increasing, and the problems as a whole are getting worse

> The problems of poverty grow worse

This specifies the problem as being specifically the "problem of poverty". i.e. the sentence as a whole means "The problems of poverty are getting worse".

Comment: I don't think you can derive "number of" out of *grow* by itself and then say that *worse* adds another clause.  The single verb phrase is *to grow worse* and it means that the severity of the problems is increasing.  Whether that is due to an increasing number of problems or to a worsening of the consequences is not specified.